# How to quickly find natural wonder?

Tags: civilization-6

I often play Hammurabi. For those who does not know, he gets -50% science, but eurekas completes any technology. So campuses are essentially only useful for getting eurekas for printing and astronomy, and for getting great scientists. Plus getting those few technologies where you simply cannot fulfill the eurekas for some reason.

So if you want a religion with Hammurabi, it's paramount to find a natural wonder. Researching astrology simply takes too much time. This means that I often have to restart a lot, which is simply not fun.

To illustrate, here is an extreme example where I am at turn 50 and have found 5 other civs and 8 city states, but no natural wonder.

[image]

Do you have any suggestions for how to get around this? A mod for finding nearest wonder would suit my needs perfectly. Or some way to ensure that there is a natural wonder within a minimum distance.

Comment: I think a good amount of wonders are found in mountain and coastal tiles, so I would probably try and explore as many as those areas as possible using a unit that has as much movement as possible.

Comment: I've removed the `civilization-6-rise-and-fall` tag as I don't believe anything specific to this question is actually relevant to "Rise and Fall" (Babylon was added as part of the separate "Babylon Pack", not the main Expansion)

Answer (score 6):

When it comes to finding Natural Wonders, you only have two real options in the base game:

- **Tilt the Dice in your Favor**
- **Reveal more of the map**

There are two other options you might want to consider, though:

- **Research Astrology Anyway**
- **Play with Religion-Indifferent Civilizations**

### Tilting the Dice

One of the options on map generation is "Legendary Start". A Legendary start includes many resources, and can result in a Natural Wonder within your starting view on turn 1. Even when it does not, other players have the same higher chance to spawn near natural wonders -- in which case, encountering city states or swapping map information about your capital with rival civilizations might inadvertently reveal a natural wonder many dozens of tiles away!

Another option is to curate the natural wonders that occur in the game. If you limit the map to never create the "Eye of the Sahara" or "Sahara el Beyda", then you can more safely ignore deserts in your early-game scouting, since you know you won't find any natural wonders in those regions. This is much more of a marginal gain, admittedly.

Both of these can be modified under "Advanced Options" on game start.

### Reveal More of the Map

A much more consistent strategy for finding Natural Wonders is simply to... reveal more of the map.

Babylon's **Sabum Kibittum** is an ideal scout unit -- not only does it share the 3 movement speed of the scout, but it has an extra +1 sight range. The usefulness of this might be underappreciated, but it can be a massive boost (at least, on more open terrain) in the number of tiles revealed / turn.

And if that's still not enough... build more Sabum Kibittum! It's not unreasonable to have as many as 3 recon units out and about (I've even wound up with 4 when tribal villages reward recon units).

### Research Astrology Anyway

While Babylon's normal research is *slow*, it's not insurmountable -- after all, you're researching Animal Husbandry, Mining, and Pottery on your own each game anyway (as they have no Eurekas)

Note that *because* of Babylon's research penalty, percentile effects, like Pingala's governor ability are relatively *more* effective; going from 50 to 65 is a 30% increase, compared to a 100 to 115, or 15% jump, for a regular civ.

### Play with Religion-Indifferent Civilizations

Not all AI Civlizations make an effort to start a religion. Stack the decks of who you invite to your game, and you'll have a better shot of earning one, even *with* a slower holy site.

Comment: It took a while for me to realize that you didn't mean astronomy :D

Comment: Researching astrology the regular way is basically a no go on higher difficulties. Sure it's not impossible to get a religion that way, but you will be very weak in all other aspects.

Comment: Oops! Yeah, definitely Astrology. Astronomy is a Renaissance tech!

Comment: Och, btw. This answer would benefit a lot if you gave some examples of civs that are unlikely to go for a religion.