# Which civilizations are most and least likely to go for religion?

Tags: civilization-6

In *Civilization VI*, which AI civilizations are most and least likely to aim for a religion?

Context: [How to quickly find natural wonder?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/405811/222252)

I want to minimize the probability of being unable to create a religion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ensure you get a religion?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/407509/how-to-ensure-you-get-a-religion)

Answer (score 6):

Here is an excerpt from [fandom.com](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Religion_(Civ6)):

> In single player games, Gilgamesh, Gorgo, Pericles, Qin Shi Huang, Trajan, Teddy Roosevelt, Victoria, Alexander, and John Curtin specifically ignore Religion. They will only go for it if they get a major advantage towards it (e.g. starting next to a natural wonder). In addition, Gandhi, Philip II, Saladin, and Jadwiga will specifically aim for an early Religion. Peter is also prone to acquiring an early religion as the Lavra is his unique district. [1](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Religion_(Civ6))

In general, you can always secure a religion, even if not starting close to a natural wonder with the exception of a difficult start and circumstances on Deity.

To guarantee you secure a religion in most scenarios:

- Research Astrology as soon as possible while trying to get boosts. But don't worry if you don't.
- Prioritize building a Holy Site even if it means building a +1 site.
- Found a second city. You can put some work into the settler as you are waiting for your research into the Holy Site and resume once the site is complete.
- Build a shrine.
- Depending on who is earning Great People points, build a Holy Site and Shrine in your second City.
- Alternatively, go for Stonehenge if you can. You may want to rush production with Magnus and a chop or two.

**Remember that Great People points is what you want to get, not adjacency.** The Holy Site rewards one and the Shrine another. If you see other cultures go for the prophets and you worry not getting one, focus on the infrastructure and then the [Holy Site Prayers](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Holy_Site_Prayers_(Civ6)) project to get you more points.

If you are focussing on Great People points, the [Divine Spark](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Divine_Spark_(Civ6)) pantheon is also a good choice as it provides additional Great People Points.