# How to ensure you get a religion?

Tags: civilization-6

I dislike not having my own religion when I play. It simply spoils the fun for me. So is there a way to ensure or at least dramatically improve the chance of getting a religion? Mods are ok.

> Previously, I asked two other questions which turned out to be [XY-problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/374458) and since they already have answers, I cannot modify them.
>
>  [Which civilizations are most and least likely to go for religion?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/405964/222252)
>
>  [How to quickly find natural wonder?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/405811/222252)
>
>  This is a self answered question. The answer I found didn't fit in any of my previous question. So I created a new one. Before that, [I discussed it in meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17046/222252)

Comment: I think building Stonehenge first is the way to go, if you want to skip mods.

Comment: @T.Sar Yes, I know, but it can be tricky to build.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which civilizations are most and least likely to go for religion?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/405964/which-civilizations-are-most-and-least-likely-to-go-for-religion)

Comment: Please refer to the answer in your question here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/405964/which-civilizations-are-most-and-least-likely-to-go-for-religion/405977#405977
Using this strategy, you will be able to ensure a religion even on Deity with a high degree of confidence.

Comment: @Eric IMO it would be better to make the other one a duplicate of this. Because any answer that would fit this question would fit the other one, but not the other way around.

Comment: I can see _maybe_ merging _Which civilizations are most and least likely to go for religion?_ with this post, but based on the close votes so far, it seems the community is (currently) leaning towards leaving this as its own/open.  Also, I see you tried to close your other question _How to quickly find natural wonders?_ as a duplicate as well, to which [the community](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/close/327089) disagreed, and so do I (that question can stand on its own, despite it having a religion-backed reason).

Answer (score -2):

Turns out there is a mod that allows you to change the number of religions which works like a charm:

https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1178185727